# Get Android Settings menu

Tags: android

Is there a way to get all menus from Settings, basically all available actions/options that are clickable in Settings?

One of the usage, for example, is if I want to set Auto-rotate screen, my app will return me a string as "Accessibility > Auto-rotate screen", then I can know how to navigate to there easily from this string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import android.provider.Settings;
public static void setAutoOrientationEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled)
{
      Settings.System.putInt( context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, enabled ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Add permission to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION)

Anyway if you need all of them, [this](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_settings) might help...

Comment: The auto rotate screen is just an example. What I want is all the options under Settings, for example, under System, there are Gestures, Backup, About phone and etc (basically a list that contains all of these options). So I can query to know what is the navigation path to a specific option.

Comment: then you need to add all of them one by one, this might be ur reference > https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to change the system value. I just want a list of all options under each menu in the Settings. There are Battery, Display, Sound, Storage, Security & Location and etc. For example, after you press on Battery, there are battery saver, battery percentage etc options in this Battery page. I just want to know all these options, toggling/changing the value is not needed.

Comment: check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html

getInt(ContentResolver cr, String name, int def) Convenience function for retrieving a single system settings value as an integer.